# RavenDB export issue

Tags: exception, export, ravendb

I am trying to export Raven db from the server and facing below shown error while exporting

[Error from Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2X08L.png)

Also i tried to export using raven smuggler (ravendb utility for db export and import through command prompt/powershell) but again got below error

[Error in Powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKzVh.png)

seems like one of the document is having an issue with one of the assignments in it.but the error doesn't give details about the document.

Could you please advise on this issue.

Comment: What RavenDB version are you using? how did you create your documents?

Comment: Hi Danielle, Version is 3.5 and Whenever we create a quote in application a document is created in RavenDB

Comment: Try in: https://groups.google.com/group/ravendb